# URL of subcategories on Magento shows 404 error page

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, 404-page, 404

I'm new on Magento. I don't know what happen with the url of sub category on Magento.

When on **www.wow.ng/customer/account/login/** OR **www.wow.ng/catalogsearch/result/** OR **www.wow.ng/checkout/cart/** I can only link to category or product page but I cannot link to subcategories. This is how it links to subcategories **www.wow.ng/checkout/cart/food-drinks.html** which gives a 404 error page. Clearly the page URL is not correct. The correct URL is **www.wow.ng/food-drinks.html** but Magento does not remove the checkout/cart OR catalogsearch/result from the url. Hope you guy can help me to fix this problem.

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Any question please feel free to ask. Thank you

Comment: How are you building the URLs of sub-categories ?

Comment: [Also posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33838059/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your category links are relative. Your links should look like this:

```
<a href="/food-drinks.html">
```

Not

```
<a href="food-drinks.html">
```

Magento give us a function to handle links:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('food-drinks.html') ?>
```

This will append the whole url and any parameters needed.

Ideally, you would get the URL from the category object encase the URL changes.

If you add some code snippets I could probably advise further. Good luck!